# I am trying to convert a georeferenced jpeg to a georeferenced tiff in order to help reduce file size

Tags: r, jpeg, tiff

I know there is a thread that has tiff to jpeg, and I used that in order to base my formatting. I have the jpeg and tiff package installed.

```
library("jpeg")
library("tiff")
jpeg<- readJPEG("ortho.jpg", native = TRUE)
tiff<- writeTIFF(jpeg,"tiff", bits.per.sample = 16L, compression = "JPEG", 
reduce = TRUE)
```

this works and and it got me a tiff, but with no attributes, therefore no georeference. my current attempt/thought process is to write the jpeg as a raster, and than go from a raster to a tiff. So i am using the raster package and the `writeRaster` function. My code at the moment is:

```
library("jpeg")
library("tiff")
jpeg<- readJPEG("ortho.jpg", native = FALSE)
raster<- as.raster(jpeg)
rf<- writeRaster(raster, filename = "rasterfile.tif" , format="GTiff")
```

This successfully writes a raster with attributes but i get an error in the `writeRaster` portion that reads,

`Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘writeRaster’ for signature ‘"raster", "character"’`

any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here was my final code that worked.

```
library(jpeg)
library(tiff)
f <- system.file("ortho.img", package="jpeg")
img <- readJPEG("ortho.jpg", native = FALSE)
writeTIFF(img, "test.tif", bits.per.sample = 8L, compression = "JPEG", reduce = TRUE)
```

Than I switched the .jgw, that referenced the jpeg to a .tfw, and autocad loaded it right up. Make sure the file names of the tfw and tif are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the `raster` package, and you should *not* use `as.raster`.

To fix your example (and using some example data!)

```
library(jpeg)
f <- system.file("img", "Rlogo.jpg", package="jpeg")
img <- readJPEG(f)

library(raster)
b <- brick(img)
plotRGB(b, scale=1)
writeRaster(b, "test.tif", overwrite=TRUE)
```

However, in that way, you will loose the georeferencing. To avoid that, you should not use the `jpeg` package at all, and do this instead:

```
library(raster)
bb <- brick(f)
writeRaster(bb, "test2.tif", overwrite=TRUE)
```

To visualize

```
plotRGB(bb)
```

See `?writeRaster` and https://www.gdal.org/frmt_gtiff.html for options that can help you reduce the file size.

Comment: Is there anyways this could be corrupting the file somehow? I am taking a jpeg that I use all the time in Autocad, follow this procedure (it all goes smooth within R, I can plot it and everything) but when i try to reload it into autocad I get an error saying that the file is corrupted.

Comment: I think it means that Autocad does not deal with GeoTiff. It seemed that this is what you wanted. How is the jpg georeferenced? Is there an additional file (perhaps with an extension like .jpw? (if so copy and rename to tfw)?

Comment: Sorry professor (you were actually my spatial analyst teacher 2 years ago), every method i used above and I cannot get any program, other than R to show the file due to corruption (windows photo viewer, autocad, arcgis, windows media player). it is referenced by an outside file, a jgw, and i changed the name to tfw with no luck. I understand if you cant dedicate anymore time to this but I appreciate the help!

Comment: If you need to use a tfw file you should probably not use a geotiff, but a normal tiff (library tiff). I find it hard to believe that ArcGIS would not read this well. It should (perhaps after recomputing some statistics for display). You can also use arcgis to write a new (geo) tiff and try your luck with that